# What is the correct way to implement a Creator Class and the Class itself design in Java?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I am trying to decide on a design for all my classes and their creators.

For example I have 2 classes, **Level** and **LevelLoader**:

The design I have come so far is:

**This is Level class:**

```
public class Level implements Serializable {

    private byte[] map; 

    Level(LevelLoader loader){
        map = loader.getMap();
    }

    // ...
}
```

**This is the Creator:**

```
public interface LevelLoader {

    public Level loadLevel(InputStream stream);

    public byte[] getMap();
}
```

So for example to create a level instance in **main** file I'll write:

**TextLoader is implementing LevelLoader interface above:**

```
File file = new File("src/Level/level2.txt");
Level level1 = new Level(new TextLoader(file));
```

So I am curious what is the most logical way to connect them to the other?

Answer (score 1):

certainly you will have more implementations in the near future. So without directly creating instances like TextLoader, get them using a Factory.

Comment: That's interesting, I am working on it right now, you are probably right :O

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I quite not get what question is about?

perhaps:
- you need to create many instances of your Level class during application run time
- also you may need different kind of loaders (TextLoader, FileLoader, URLLoader and so on..)

Then you can create each loader once somewhere outside (i.e. Utiltiy or ObjectFactory class) and then reuse them to create instances.

something like that:

**ObjectFactory class**

```
private static LevelLoader filetLoaderInstance = new FileLoader("level2.txt");
private static LevelLoader urlLoaderInstance = new URLLoader("ftp://foo.com/level2.txt");

public static Level createLevelFromFile()
{
   return new Level(textLoaderInstance);
}

public static Level createLevelFromURL()
{
   return new Level(urlLoaderInstance);
}
```

In general without necessity of multiple usage such design is not needed.
Like in your example with

```
Level level1 = new Level(new TextLoader(file));
```

It is quite overhead. What is the reason to have and create another object (TextLoader) if it will run only once?

But if that code has to run many times - it is not good. It is better to have only one instance of TextLoader rather than create it every time when instance of Loader class creates.
It affects memory usage as well as performance of application.

Comment: That code has to run many times, as every level the user moves forward or loads new levels. So I understand now from your answer that I should go for Factory pattern instead.

Comment: I think it can be quite of both patterns. There is another advantage of this pattern. It is good to create API Framework when developer of Level class does not know ahead about possible implementations of LevelLoader, and actually does not care. He can create DefaultLoader but leave opportunity to make more other kinds.

Answer (score 0):

What I feel is the below way.

```
InputStream is = new File("src/Level/level2.txt");
LevelLoader levelLoader = new TextLoader();
Level level = levelLoader.loadLevel(file);
```

Comment: thanks for the feedback. I was thinking about going that way also, why do you prefer using a method instead of a c'tor ?

Comment: You can see all the left hand side variables are of interfaces, if you implement these interfaces in some other classes, then this will be prefect one. E.g `LevelLoader levelLoader = new SimpleLevelLoader();`

Comment: If you want to gather some information from the file then you require to have a constructor but here you can use both, the other option is you can call this method from constructor.